# Why S3 bucket is not getting created though it is mentioned in SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am trying to create a lambda function with function code in the S3 bucket. Below is my template.
This template creates the lambda but, not the S3 bucket mentioned. I am looking for assistance to create S3 bucket through this template.

```
Resources:
  ProducerLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub '${ApplicationId}-${env}-Producer-Lambda-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}'
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: s3bucket   
        Key: s3bucketref.zip
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/Producer-lambda-trigger-role' 
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: !Ref VPCSubnetId
      Environment:
        Variables:
          Region: !Sub '${AWS::Region}'
```

Comment: Is there a zip file in the bucket?

Answer (score 2):

[`CodeUri`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html) is used to specify the path to the function's code - this can be an Amazon S3 URI, the path to a local folder, or a `FunctionCode` object.

They are not used to create S3 buckets.

If the packaged function does not exist at `s3bucket/s3bucketref.zip` then you will have to create the bucket yourself and upload the package.

Or alternatively, using [`sam build`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html) will build the Lambda for you & [`sam deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html) will then automatically create an S3 bucket for you:

> Deploying AWS Lambda functions through AWS CloudFormation requires an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket for the Lambda deployment package. **The AWS SAM CLI creates and manages this Amazon S3 bucket for you.**

The latter is much simpler to manage.